# When does parsing HTML DOM tree happen?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I always see a rendering flow for a web page like the following image shows:
[image]

So the painting only begins after DOM tree is parsed and CSSOM is created, right? Another saying is, putting `<script>` in the end of `<body>` is the best practice so that the page renders something before script is downloaded.

My question is, when does parsing DOM tree happens and how can we say it is done? In my understanding, `<script>` in the end is also *part of DOM tree*, and only if the script loaded can we call the DOM tree is created. The browser reads the html file from top to bottom, creating the DOM Tree and when it sees a `<script>`, it stops to download and execute it until the parse goes through the whole page. Or, does the page paints the page at the same time of parsing DOM tree?

Comment: Offtopic: is fun to see how a question like this (question with a good quality) receives a downvote. It demonstrate the trolls that still exists in stackoverflow. @JasmineOT your question is good!

Comment: @MarcosPérezGude Thanks a lot Marcos, it really bothers me for a long time.

Comment: i had to dig through my browser history: i have used [this article](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/internals/howbrowserswork/) to comprehend it. it also states (see section main flow) *The rendering engine will start getting the contents of the requested document from the networking layer. This will usually be done in 8kB chunks.*

Comment: @JasmineOT: This graphic only shows the flow for a single entitity, from the resoource till it appears on the screen. It does not deal with updates, like the network spitting out the next chunk to be parsed or the DOM being modifyed through JS. You have to imagine this flow taking place multiple times, or even continuously.

Comment: The webpage https://jackgiffin.com/main/books/Starnes-The-Practice-of-Statistics-AP-5e.html is a perfect demonstration: even though it is a 69MB webpage, it still presents itself to the user reasonably fast by sprinkling inline `<script>` elements throughout the HTML so that as soon as the page you are at has finished downloading, it is presented to the user before the rest of the webpage has loaded. Surprisingly, all browsers that I have tested have displayed the webpage before the entire file finished downloading: Chrome, Firefox, Safari, Edge, Opera Mini, and even Internet Explorer 11.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

TL;DR: Parsing starts **instantaneously** after receiving the document.

#### Parsing and painting

For a more detailed explanation, we need to dive into the way rendering engines work.

Rendering engines parse the HTML document and create two trees: the `content tree` and the `render tree`. A content tree contains all DOM nodes. The render tree contains all styling information (the `CSSOM`) and *only* the DOM nodes that are required to render te page.

As soon as the render tree has been created, the browsers goes through two processes: applying `layout` and `painting` each DOM node. Applying layout means calculating the exact coordinates where a DOM node should appear on the screen. Painting means actually rendering the pixels and applying stylistic properties.

This is a gradual process: browsers won't wait until all HTML is parsed. Parts of the content will be parsed and displayed, while the process continues with the rest of the contents that keeps coming from the network.

You can see this process happening in your browser. For example, open the Chrome Developer Tools and load a site of your choice.

[image: Network tab]

After recording activity in the `Network` tab, you'll notice that parsing starts *while* downloading the document. It recognises resources and starts downloading them. The blue vertical line indicates the `DOMContentLoaded` event and the red vertical line indicates the `load` event.

[image: Timeline tab]

Recording a timeline gives you much more insight in what happens under the hood. I have included the screenshot above as an example to indicate that painting happens while parsing the document. Note that the initial paint occurs just before it continues parsing another part of the document. This process continues until it reaches the end of the document.

#### Single threaded

The rendering engine is *single threaded*. Almost everything, except network operations, happens in this thread.

Combine that with the *synchronous* nature of the web. Developers expect `<script>`'s to be parsed and executed immediately (that is: as soon as the parser reaches a script tag). That means that:

1. The resource must be fetched from the network (this might be a slow process due to DNS lookups and speed of connection).
2. The content of the resource is passed to the Javascript interpreter.
3. The interpreter parses and executes the code.

Parsing the document halts until this process finishes. You don't improve the total parsing time by including `<script>`'s at the end of the document. It does **enhance the user experience**, as the process of  parsing and painting isn't interrupted by `<script>`'s that need to be executed.

It is possible to work around this issue by marking the resource with `defer` and / or `async`. `async` downloads the file during HTML parsing and will pause the HTML parser to execute it when it has finished downloading. `defer` downloads the file during HTML parsing and will only execute it after the parser has completed.

#### Speculative parsing

Some browsers aim to work around the blocking aspect of `<script>`'s by using so called speculative parsing. The engine parses ahead (and runs the HTML tree construction!) while scripts are being downloaded and executed. Firefox and Chrome use this technique.

You can imagine the performance gain if a speculation succeeds (eg. the DOM wasn't altered by the scripts that are included in the document). Waiting for the scripts to execute wasn't necessary and the page has been painted successfully.
The downside is that there's more work lost when the speculation fails.

Luckily for us, very smart people work at these technologies, so even using `document.write` properly won't break this process. Another rule of thumb is not to use `document.write`. For example, it could break the speculative tree:

```
// Results in an unbalanced tree
<script>document.write("<div>");</script>

// Results in an unfinished token
<script>document.write("<div></div");</script>
```

#### Further reading

The following resources are worth your time reading:

- [Web Fundamentals](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/performance/critical-rendering-path/render-tree-construction) (Google Developers)
- [How browsers work](http://taligarsiel.com/Projects/howbrowserswork1.htm#Introduction)
- MDN on [HTML5 Parser](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/HTML5/HTML5_Parser)
- [An introduction to Browser Rendering](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=n1cKlKM3jYI) (video)

Answer (score 2):

> Another saying is, putting `<script>` in the end of `<body>` is the best practice so that the page renders something before script is downloaded.

The major reason of putting script tag to the end of body tag is: **download** and **execute** JavaScripts will block HTML parsing (or, you can say they are just parts of parsing). If they are put in the `<head>`, the user may wait for a long time before he could see anything on web page. Image you have a html page like this:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <!-- this huge.js takes 10 seconds to download -->
    <script src="huge.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div>
      My most fancy div!
    </div>
  </body>
</html>

// huge.js
(function () {
   // Some CPU intensive JS operations which take 10 second to complete
})();
```

The browser will start to execute those CPU-intensive JS right after it reaches that `<script>` tag. And it will **block** parsing the rest of the HTML content. So in this case, the user won't be able to see his fancy div before that JavaScript is downloaded and executed (takes 20 seconds in total).

You can use `DOMContentLoaded` to detect whether the initial DOM is loaded and parsed. And your statement in last paragraph is quite correct: every time HTML parser see a `<script>`, it will download and execute it synchronously (see **Notice 2**). After all `<script>` are executed and all HTML is parsed, `DOMContentLoaded` will be fired.

**Notice 1**: `DOMContentLoaded` will NOT wait for CSS and images

**Notice 2**: Most browsers have "Speculative parsing" feature. If there are multiple JavaScript files, they will be downloaded simultaneous. However, they will still be executed sequential by the main thread.

For your last question:

> Or, does the page paints the page at the same time of parsing DOM tree?

From my own understanding, the answer is **YES**, the browser will try to paint **ASAP**. That is to say, the paint engine won't wait for render tree is fully ready. So there should be a separated thread to handle the paint.

Feel free to correct me if any of my understanding is wrong :)

References:

1. https://www.chromium.org/developers/the-rendering-critical-path
2. http://taligarsiel.com/Projects/howbrowserswork1.htm

Answer (score 1):

This is actually dependent on the browser as to the specific order that everything is loaded but for DOM parsing it works top to bottom. The parser moves branch by branch, so when it encounters the head, it will move through each child. If an element has a child it will then move onto the child/children before moving back up the tree. To put that in very basic pseudo-code:

```
while DOM != parsed:
    if current_node.has_child():
        current_node = child_node
        execute_node()
    elif current_node.has_sibling():
        current_node = sibling_node
        execute_node()
    elif current_node.has_parent_sibling():
        current_node = parent_sibling
        execute_node()
    else:
        current_node = parent_node
```

It essentially deals with script/link tags as parent nodes, initiate a HTTP/S GET Request if it's an external file and parse the code before moving on to the next node. So the reason we use put script tags at the end is because they usually aren't used at page load, but handle things after it is loaded. So the consensus is that it's better to get something on the page then load your JS later so that it can handle that *oh so important* animation you have on a menu item.

There are of course exception to this, whereby you can specify to the DOM parser to execute scripts asynchronously - the parser creates an extra thread to parse the JS - or defer - GET Request is made but the file is not parsed until the HTML Document is finished parsing.