# Async code executed between <script> tags

Tags: javascript, html, asynchronous

I'm a NodeJs developer that happens to have some web applications.
I'm very familiar with asynchronous code and how the event loop works. However I been facing a problem that I was unable to fix until I realized that asynchronous code may behave different when it is splitted across several script tags.
The situation was as follows

- I had one script tag at the head section with some asynchronous code. Such code expected some function to exist. That function should be declared on the second script tag in a synchronous fashion, so at the time the async stuff completes that function should exist.
- Te second script tag is 100% synchronous and at the middle of the code it created a function called boot.

Let me ilustrate it with some simplified code:

```
// <script>
 somePromise()
    .then( ()=> window.boot())
// </script>
// < ... some html code and body >
// <script>
window.boot = function (){}
// </script>
```

Since the promise callback should be executed asynchronously I expected it to go to the event loop and allow the rest of the synchronous code to execute.

On some browsers, this worked as I expect. When I say some browsers I mean browsers of different users on different computers, because the behavior varies even using the same browser brand and version. However, there were situations when the promise callback was executed before the second second script tag had a chance to start and raising an error.

How is this supposed to work on browsers ? Is each script tag executed until all its code is executed, even the asynchronous one ? If that is the case, why does it work for some other browsers?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: All scripts should be at the bottom of body tag (widely accepted convention). Try doing the same.

Comment: Is the second script loaded using a `src` attribute in the script tag?

Comment: @traktor53 both scripts contain the actual code to be executed.

Comment: @waleed-lqbal I am using a framework that has this already structured this way, and In any case my question is not about how to solve the problem, I have several ways to solve it, it is about understanding the actual behavior.

Comment: Because sometimes the promise wins (loses?) the race against the network and parser and executes before the other code is ready. Why create this race condition in the first place without a safety check and retry window?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The HTML5 parser is not synchronous.

This is my own reworded extract of parts of [HTML Parser Threading on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Gecko/HTML_parser_threading). Please refer to the original for formal treatment and heavy reading.

> HTML between the script tag [pairs] is parsed by a `nsHtml5StreamParser` which executes off the main thread.
>
> The parser runs its own event loop, and responds to requests from the main thread to perform `onDataAvailable` and `OnStopRequest` processing. Processing calls `DoDataAvailable` and `doStopRequst` respectively.
>
> `DoDataAvailable` outputs small DOM tree operations, such as element creation into a queue processed in the main thread. The tree op queue is flushed to the main thread from time to time ** using a timer.**
>
> After flushing the parser dispatches a runnable to the main thread to process tree additions. The runner (or executor) in the main thread calls `nsHtml5TreeOpExecutor::RunFlushLoop().`

A comment from @KarelG in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34269416/5217142) says that network data is usually processed in 8Kb chunks. The question is well worth reading.

So the JavaScript Event Loop sometimes gets an opportunity to fulfill a promise and execute an `onFulfilled` handler before the second script element is parsed and executed - as you already discovered!

In summary it apppear that the vagaries of network retrieval of source code, asynchronous HTML parsing that uses a timer to instigate processing of tree building operations, and any further asynchronous operations that the tree builder may or may not invoke, all combine together to create a race condition.

The unpredictability of the failure branch of the race condition, when `window.boot` is not defined when called, is most likely due to the combined effects of browser brand, network speed, device utilization, length and type of HTML content, and HTML parser timing and timers.

The obvious conclusion is that code should not set up this kind of race condition in the first place. It is unsafe coding practice. Thankfully you can work around it.

Comment: That is an awesome answer. Thank you very much. As I said, I found a solution, but having this explanation (and it's references) fulfills my curiosity entirely. Race conditions are surely evil, but sometimes you don't even realize they're there.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, promise is not suported in IE, so what you could do is to use some external libs, like bluebirdJS, or you could use a transpiler (babel or another one)